# Json to blade view

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, laravel, laravel-blade

I try to display json result to my blade view but nothing is display I would like to know where I'm doing wrong and why the result in the table is not display.

I have a table with values and the values change with a select box

I checked when in enter the url like this :

```
https://mydomaine.eu/go/ready/public/competition/search/equipes?poule_id=2
```

I get this result :

```
table   "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html l…>\n\n</body>\n</html>\n"
equipes 
0   
id  7
equipe_id   14
poule_id    2
lb_equipe   "Test"
lb_club_equipe  "XIII LIMOUXIN"
nm_club_equipe  "111343"
equipe  Object
```

in my controller I have :

```
public function searchEquipes(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->has('poule_id')) {
        $equipes = EquipePoule::where('poule_id' , $request->poule_id)->get();
        ................

        return response()->json([
                'table' => view("competitions/show", compact('equipes',
                 'competition', 'categorie_age', 'categorie_compet',
                 'classements' , 'equipe_to_select', 'structure_rattachement',
                 'poules', 'select_poules', 'journee_to_select',
                 'journees', 'rencontres', 'designations', 'stade',
                 'domicile' , 'visiteur'))->render(),
                'equipes' => $equipes,
            ]);

    } else {
        //nothing
    }
}
```

here my table to display the result with the select box to change the result  :

```
<select id="poule">
@foreach($select_poules as $select_poule)
    <option value="{{$select_poule->id}}">{{$select_poule->lb_poule}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>

<table id="equipes" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Club</th>
            <th>Nom de l'équipe</th>
            <th>Bonus(+/-)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($equipes as $equipe)
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="{!! route('club.show', $equipe->equipe->structure->id) !!}">{{$equipe->equipe->structure->nom_structure}}</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="{!! route('equipe.show', $equipe->equipe->id) !!}">{{$equipe->equipe->lb_equipe}}</a>
            </td>
            <td>{!! Form::text('nb_bonus') !!}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

here my script :

```
<script>
$('#poule').change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url : 'search/equipes',
        dataType: "json",
        data : {
            poule_id : document.getElementById('poule').value
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#equipes').html(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks a lot in advance if someone could help

Comment: Try pressing CTRL+U in your browser to view the raw json output.

Comment: it's look like i have all my web page in json

Comment: But that is what you wanted isn't it? `response()->json()` will always send a json object back to the browser.

Comment: i would like to just display my table with my foreach loop equipes as equipe